# Passing variable to a dojo widget constructor

Tags: javascript, dojo

Below code is a representation of my widget. Here I am trying to access variables which are passed from another js.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/_base/lang"], function(declare, lang,){
    return declare("myapplication.viewer.js.dynamicview",null,{

        getTextBoxValue:null,

        constructor : function(args){
            alert("inside constructor");
            console.log("args",args);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my js from where I am calling my widget.

```
var abc={};
abc.title="helloworld";
var viewerWidget = new myapplication.viewer.js.dynamicview({getTextBoxValue:abc});
```

Here I am passing an object to my widget variable.
But the problem is that in my widget, args variable in constructor is undefined. I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Need to get value from my js to my widget.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixin properties of your widget. That is a step later in your widget. See [widget lifecycle here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html).

Your best option is to use `postMixInProperties` and not the constructor for this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"dojo/_base/lang"` (mixin) to add new properties to the instance of your class,

use the mixin function (`lang.mixin()`):

```
constructor : function(args){
   //below add new properties to the current instance
   lang.mixin(this, args);

   alert("inside constructor");
   console.log("args",args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mixin` in order to "extend" your dojo class with the properties or routines as you wish.

A full example here;

https://jsfiddle.net/tsb3g6f9/9/

More resources here:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html

```
require(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dojo/_base/lang'], function(declare, lang) {
  var MyClass = declare(null, {
    constructor: function(args) {
      lang.mixin(this, args);
    },
    action: function() {
      alert(this.a);
    }
  });
  var obj = {
    a: 100
  }
  var thomas = new MyClass(obj);
  thomas.action();

});
```